# JavaFX - center origin at center of pane rather than top left

Tags: javafx

I am trying to build a hex grid by following along with [Red Blob Games](https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/implementation.html). The hex grid axial coordinate system runs from `-radius < x < radius` and `-radius < y < radius`. Red Blob defines a function that converts the `int` axial coordinates into a `double` pixel coordinate.

```
public Point tileToPixel(Tile tile) {
    Hex hex = (Hex) tile;
    double x = (orientation.getF0() * hex.getX() + orientation.getF1() * hex.getY()) * size.getX();
    double y = (orientation.getF2() * hex.getX() + orientation.getF3() * hex.getY()) * size.getY();
    return new Point(x, y);
}
```

`Point` is equivalent to `Point2D`; I decided to write my own.

`orientation` is an `enum` that defines the points of the hexagon based on a flat-top or point-top hexagon orientation.

```
POINT_TOP_ORIENTATION   (   Math.sqrt(3.0), Math.sqrt(3.0)/2.0, 0.0, 3.0/2.0,
                            Math.sqrt(3.0)/3.0, -1.0/3.0, 0.0, 2.0/3.0,
                            0.5),

FLAT_TOP_ORIENTATION    (   3.0/2.0, 0.0, Math.sqrt(3.0)/2.0, Math.sqrt(3.0),
                            2.0/3.0, 0.0, -1.0/3.0, Math.sqrt(3.0)/3.0,
                            0.0);

private HexOrientation(double f0, double f1, double f2, double f3, 
                        double b0, double b1, double b2, double b3,
                        double startAngle) {
    this.f0 = f0;
    this.f1 = f1;
    this.f2 = f2;
    this.f3 = f3;
    this.b0 = b0;
    this.b1 = b1;
    this.b2 = b2;
    this.b3 = b3;
    this.startAngle = startAngle;
}
```

The problem becomes that the axial coordinate is converted to a pixel coordinate `double` that includes negative values and assumes a normal Cartesian format (positive Y up, positive X right) with the origin being (0,0) at the center.

I am using Scene Builder to construct my display. Here is my extremely basic set-up:

[image: Scene Builder]

You can see that I have the `AnchorPane` as root, a `BorderPane`, and a `Pane` located in the center of the `BorderPane` where I intend my Hexagons to be displayed.

My `Main` class is defined:

```
public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    try {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/Display.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);    
        stage.setTitle("Grid Display");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

My FXML class is defined:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.ScreenController">
   <children>
      <BorderPane layoutX="-8.0" layoutY="-69.0" prefHeight="297.0" prefWidth="610.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <center>
            <Pane fx:id="nodePane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
         </center>
      </BorderPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Lastly, my controller class, `ScreenController` is defined:

```
public class ScreenController {

@FXML
private Pane nodePane;

@FXML
protected void initialize() {
    Grid grid = new Grid(new HexScreen(HexOrientation.POINT_TOP_ORIENTATION, new Point (10,10)), new HexMap(MapShape.HEXAGON));

    for(Tile tile : grid.getMap().getMap()) {
        int i = 0;
        Double[] points = new Double[12];
        Point[] corners = grid.getScreen().polygonCorners(tile);
        for(Point point : corners) {
            points[i] = point.getX();
            points[i+1] = point.getY();
            i += 2;
        }
        Polygon polygon = drawTile(points);
        if (tile.getX() == 0 && tile.getY() == 0) {
            polygon.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        }

        this.nodePane.getChildren().add(polygon);
    }
}

private Polygon drawTile(Double[] points) {

    Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
    polygon.getPoints().addAll(points);
    polygon.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    polygon.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    return polygon;
}
```

}

The output of this is:

[image: Output]

How can I set the origin of the `nodePane` to be in the center of the `Pane` rather than the top left? I would rather not recalculate the pixel coordinates via the `tileToPixel()` because this function is located in a project that I import as a JAR into the `GridDisplay` project where the actual JavaFX display is occurring. I intend to be able to use that JAR as a library independent of how I am building the GUI and thus need "universal" tile to pixel calculations and not JavaFX specific (if that makes sense).

Therefore, I think the most appropriate place to change the pixel coordinates is in the `ScreenController`. So far I have tried:

```
        for(Tile tile : grid.getMap().getMap()) {
        int i = 0;
        Double[] points = new Double[12];
        Point[] corners = grid.getScreen().polygonCorners(tile);
        for(Point point : corners) {
            points[i] = point.getX();
            points[i+1] = point.getY();
            i += 2;
        }
        Polygon polygon = drawTile(points);
        if (tile.getX() == 0 && tile.getY() == 0) {
            polygon.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        }

        polygon.setTranslateX(nodePane.getWidth()/2);
        polygon.setTranslateY(nodePane.getHeight()/2);

        this.nodePane.getChildren().add(polygon);
    }
```

The output of this looks exactly the same as the above image. I have also substituted `nodePane.getWidth()` and `nodePane.getHeight()` for:

```
    polygon.setTranslateX(nodePane.getPrefWidth()/2);
    polygon.setTranslateY(nodePane.getPrefHeight()/2);
```

This moves the origin slightly but not how I imagine it should look. For reference, the `PrefWidth` and `PrefHeight` for my `AnchorPane`, `BorderPane`, and `Pane` are all set at `USE_COMPUTED_SIZE`.

[image: PrefWidth and PrefHeight]

Finally, even if the above solution at centered my origin at the center of the `Pane`, I don't believe it would work if a user resized the window.

Thank you for reading my lengthy post, please let me know if you require any additional information.

Comment: it may work if you put your `nodePane` inside a `StackPane`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Sedrick thank you for your help.

Here is my solution.

```
public class ScreenController {

@FXML
private StackPane nodePane;

@FXML
protected void initialize() {
    Grid grid = new Grid(new HexScreen(HexOrientation.POINT_TOP_ORIENTATION, new Point (10,10)), new HexMap(MapShape.HEXAGON));
    Group group = new Group();
    for(Tile tile : grid.getMap().getMap()) {
        int i = 0;
        Double[] points = new Double[12];
        Point[] corners = grid.getScreen().polygonCorners(tile);
        for(Point point : corners) {
            points[i] = point.getX();
            points[i+1] = point.getY();
            i += 2;
        }
        Polygon polygon = drawTile(points);
        if (tile.getX() == 0 && tile.getY() == 0) {
            polygon.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        }
        group.getChildren().add(polygon);
    }
    this.nodePane.getChildren().add(group);
}

private Polygon drawTile(Double[] points) {

    Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
    polygon.getPoints().addAll(points);
    polygon.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    polygon.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    //tileHandler.hoverHandler(polygon, Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.RED);
    return polygon;
}
```

}

I first put all the polygons (hexs) into a `Group` object. Then added the `Group` to a `StackPane` (instead of a `Pane`), as suggested above. This solution did not work if I used a `Pane` instead of a `Group`. Here is the resultant output:

[image: Good Output]

I still need to mirror the grid across the X axis (because -Y is still up) and preferably allow for dynamic resizing of the grid with window resizing so the full grid is always in view.